# Error Checking does not work properly for Parse Query

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-platform

So I have a class in the parse server called "classes" and I tried to implement an error-checking query inside my program. The Xcode project builds properly, however, when I attempt to error check my query to search for classes, the program always says the search is a success, even though an object of that class type is not in the query. Here is the code:

```
  @IBAction func searchClass(_ sender: Any) {

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Classes")
    query.findObjectsInBackground { (success, error) in
        if error != nil{
            self.createAlert(title: "Error", message: "Cannot find class")
        } else {
            self.createAlert(
                title: "Success", message: "Found the query")
            self.classSuccess = true
            self.flipCardButton.alpha = 0
            UIView.transition(from: self.classQuery, to: self.classRate, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionFlipFromRight)
            self.goBackButton.alpha = 1
        }
    }
```

And here was the search button inside of my application:

[Screenshot of Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjtFF.png)

What could possibly go wrong to make the parse query check always print success?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your missing the success statement in your query.

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Classes")
query.findObjectsInBackground { (success, error) in
    if error != nil{
        print(error ?? "") 
        self.createAlert(title: "Error", message: "Cannot find class")
    } 

    if success {
        self.createAlert(
            title: "Success", message: "Found the query")
        self.classSuccess = true
        self.flipCardButton.alpha = 0
        UIView.transition(from: self.classQuery, to: self.classRate, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionFlipFromRight)
        self.goBackButton.alpha = 1

    } else {
       self.createAlert(title: "Error", message: "Cannot find class")
    }
}
```